# Some changes in the user.ini has no affect

Tags: php

I have this configuration in `.user.ini`

```
error_reporting = 14327
display_errors = 1
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 30M
```

I checked `phpinfo()` local values are loaded correctly from `.user.ini.`

But my script still failing with this error:

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 13394723 bytes exceeds
> the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

what should cause that `ini_get(post_max_size) return 30M` but script failing at 8M (server defalut set in php.ini)?

Comment: You probably didn't restart the CGI process.

Comment: I don't need restart php-fpm and apache. User.ini file was set to reload every 10s and all changes like display_error work before just fine.